# Sorting a Mongoid Object via its Associated Model's Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having some problems trying to understand how Mongoid does its sorting. I have 2 models, Gig and Venue, both of which are associated by a belong_to has_many relationship.

I'm trying to sort objects from Gig by the attribute 'name' of the Venue Object to no avail.

I'm hoping someone out there would be able to point me to the right direction.

Below are a truncated model description.

My Query is also below:

```
# Gig Model
class Gig 
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  include SearchMagic

  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :owns
  belongs_to :venue

  has_and_belongs_to_many :attenders, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :attending

  has_and_belongs_to_many :artistes

<snip>
end

# Venue Model
class Venue
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  include SearchMagic

  has_many :gigs
  field :foursquare_id, type: String
  embeds_one :address
  embeds_many :user_ratings

  field :facebook, type: String
  field :twitter, type: String
  field :website, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :postal, type: String
  field :tel, type: String
  field :venue_type, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :rating, type: Float, default: 0.0

<snip>
end


# Console

>> Gig.desc('venue.name').map{|f| f.venue.name}                                            
=> ["*SCAPE", "Velvet Underground", "Blujaz Lounge", "Velvet Underground", "Home Club", "Wh
ite House, Emily Hill", "Zouk", "Zouk", "The Pigeonhole", "Home Club", "Home Club", "Home C
lub"]

# sorting doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't join in mongo. If you need joins, use a relational database. A "feature" of non-relational databases is that you can't do joins.

You have basically two choices:

1. a before_save callback, which will inject the name of the venue into the gig as an additional field (see for instance https://github.com/rewritten/timebank/blob/master/lib/mongoid/denormalize.rb)
2. a map-reduce task, which after any modification of any venue or gig, will update the venue name into the gig as an additional field.

In the end, you need a field in the Gig collection to order it.